# Is it possible to have an EC2 communicate with another Elasticache from another region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I have an EC2 instance in the Asia Pacific (Singapore) region that I'd like to connect to a Elasticache instance launched in Oregon (US-West) region.

After reading through, I understand that Elasticache can only be access from instances within the same VPC.

Is there a way to allow for such communications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but not directly. You can use something like HA Proxy to provide access. This could defeat the purpose of Elasticache though - you may want to use vanillia Redis so you can synch using the Redis native tools otherwise your queries are going to have some serious latency.

Comment: Thanks! You mean like a haproxy sitting in the same region as the elasticache which would then forward the packets from the other region into?

Comment: Yes but it will probably really slow (relatively speaking) because of the latency between Singapore and the US. Depending on your use case you may want to use a Redis cluster (with nodes in each region) or a message queue.